# Special characters in SQL: '≥' sign is being saved as an '=' sign in my rows in a SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In a varchar field I am trying to add the following thing:

`'something ≥ something_else'`.

This gets saved as `'something = something_else'`

I have done some research about this and the most popular answer is adding the N prefix, which I have tried:

```
N'something ≥ something_else'
```

Once I hit save, this will still be saved as

```
N'something = something_else'
```

The table collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS if that matters. How can I save these characters in the varchar field?

Comment: If you need a N-prefixed literal, you also need nvarchar column instead of varchar.

Comment: So if I need a name containing ≥, this would be considered an nvarchar? So what I have to do is change the varchar to nvarchar ?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c63ec5/alter-column-data-type-in-mysql/